# Is it possible to have a section of code in the preamble evaluated last in pythontex?

Tags: pythontex

I have a situation where a series of plots are generated using PythonTeX within my document, wherein they all append to a global "preamble" variable.

I want to be able to print this variable into the preamble after evaluating the document, such that the preamble will contain all the custom code (colourmaps for pgfplots, etc.) that I need for the document.

Is this at all possible?  Perhaps through some "post-eval" hook within pythontex itself?